# Desactivar opciones de formulario / ventana (minimizar, maximizar y cerrar) y this.dispose(); no funciona (Java Net Beans 13)

Tags: java, apache-netbeans

Bueno, doy detalles técnicos:

- Estoy haciendo un sistema en Java Net Beans 13. El cual, lo estoy construyendo con formularios (JForms / Marven).
- Estoy tratando de buscar la opción de quitar las opciones de  (minimizar, maximizar y cerrar) para que el usuario use el botón de "Salir".
  [image: Formulario]  Tengo entendido que el nombre del método es: "undecorated" en false, pero, por alguna razón no lo encuentro. Entonces, la primer pregunta es: ¿Cómo es / cómo se llama ahora dicha opción / método?
- Ahora, en el botón salir:
  private void btnSalirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  this.dispose();
  }
  El código de "dispose();" no funciona, de hecho dice que: "No encuentra el método de dispose()". Se que puedo esconderla, hacerla invisible. Pero, lo que deseo es cerrarla (porque si la escondo o hago invisible, esta aún seguirá activa en memoria y las estaciones / clientes, no tienen mucha RAM). También tengo entendido que si uso el botón de X se cierra, pero, si hay un formulario padre / MDI este se cerrará. Entonces, por eso deseo solo cerrar el formulario y desactivar las opciones de las ventanas / formularios / Jforms.

Recuerdo, que en C# solo era "this.close();" y ya... Pero, aquí me estoy dando contra la pared en cosas muy sencillas.

Soy un perfecto novato en Net Beans, por favor... Sean claros y sencillos. Gracias y saludos.

Comment: el metodo es setUndecorated();

Comment: Hola. ¿Sería así?: FrmCatalogoEnfermedades.setUndecorated(false);  - Porque, no me acepta: "setUndecorated();"

Comment: claro por que es un método de la clase Jframe ,para mas ayuda es recomendable que adjuntes parte del código donde estas teniendo el inconveniente,saludos

Comment: Tienes razón. Ya he logrado hacerlo. Y también encontré la causa raíz de estos problemas.... Estoy usando un JPanel y no un Jframe. En el JPanel, NO tiene dichos métodos. Entonces, he puesto un JFrame y si los tiene. Error de un completo novato e ignorante. Pero, también así los cometí en .NET. Saludos y gracias.